# Can't Run Bitcoin Wallet After It was Downloaded on Windows 8.1 Desktop

Tags: wallet

Please help.  After downloading the Bitcoin wallet, I don't have the option to 'run' it on my windows 8.1.  It was a compressed file, and even though I extracted everything, there is nothing that indicates what contents need to be opened (ran).  I have doubled clicked all 'applications' in that file.

I can only get the window that asks if I want to buy coins.  When I click buy, it wants my email address (that I didn't have an option to set up).  When I click 'Don't have one,' it sends me back to the download Bitcoin Wallet screen.

Comment: Which wallet are you talking about?